# Use ESC Key to leave html5 video fullscreen

Tags: html, fullscreen, html5-video, mediaelement.js

So I have been embeding html5 videos into my website as of late using the mediaelement.js script.  It works really great and seems like be the least buggy.  However, I am simply trying to add the function that when pressing the ESC key, it takes you out of full screen mode, I have done a lot of searching and it doesnt seem like anybody has asked this question, which makes me think it is a simple oversight.  But nontheless I need to figure it out to satisfy my client.  Thanks

Media Element Website: http://mediaelementjs.com/

Update: It is only Chrome from what I can tell that it doesn't work in

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/
maybe something like that, media element should have a function you can call to reduce the window size. ESC has keycode 27 if I'm not wrong